# SAPUI5: How to bind a click event to horizontal layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

Hi I'm developing my view in JS and I'm stuck in binding a click handler for my horizontal layout element. I've tried using Jquery

```
$("#myHorizontalLayout").bind("click",function(){window.alert()});
```

Which didn't work then I tried using `attachPress` with the element which obviously didn't exist. Please help.

**Update:**

The JS view is the default view of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `on/bind` does not work, it could be that the HTML of the control has actually not been created yet at this point in time. But even if you delay the binding, the re-rendering (re-creation of the HTML after changes) would remove your listener, at least when bound on the control itself.

A proper way of doing this is using the generic `attachBrowserEvent` function available on every control (here: on the layout) which internally handles all the rendering/rerendering stuff, see this example:
http://jsbin.com/hijutunefi/1/edit?html,output

`attachBrowserEvent` works for any browser event, as it attaches a new browser event listener to the root node of the control. For the most common browser events UI5 does event delegation, so for the "click" event and several others `addEventDelegate` can also be used, as pointed out by aborjinik.

Alternatively, listening on the `<body>` level with normal jQuery mechanisms should in general also work.

Comment: as the name implies attachBrowserEvent will add event listeners to specific node. Instead of adding many event listeners, event delegation can be used as well http://jsbin.com/kemejojate/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

> Which didn't work then I tried using attachPress with the element which obviously didn't exist. Please help.

Does this means that the element on which you are attaching event handler doesn't exists at this point? If this is the case you can hook the handler to some container, upper in the DOM hierarchy which you are sure that exists and filter the click events.

Example:

```html
$("body").on("click", "#myHorizontalLayout", function(){
  alert("Hey, you!");
});
```

Comment: Im Sorry this is not working too. `which obviously didn't exist` by this i mean to say that there was no method called `.attachPress()` associated with the element.

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs.

[Reference here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

So try replacing `bind` with `on` and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Any errors in your console log? If so post it, if not you need to update your question with more information, like when is your view being loaded when and when is your js being executed. Are there any previous events attached to that element?

Comment: There are no errors in my console log. And my view is being called on the init of the application.

Comment: Is your js code wrapped around a $(document).ready(function(){}); ?